# Bitshift Int Color back to RGB

Tags: python, software-design

I'm writing in Python but I'm sure other languages have the same approach.

I'm coding a tool for a 3D Software (Softimage) and the SDK manual doesn't specify anything about how I need to specify the color and I got to this conclusion just by trial and error looking for some codes in the internet.

The color needed to be specified with an integer number which I get it like this:

With colors in 0-255 values:

```
Rvalue | Gvalue << 8 | Bvalue << 16 | Avalue << 24
```

It seems to work perfectly, now I'd like to convert this integer number back to `RGBA` values. How should I proceed ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert Integers to RGB values and back with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33124347/convert-integers-to-rgb-values-and-back-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
R = color & 255
G = (color >> 8) & 255
B = (color >> 16) & 255
A = (color >> 24) & 255
```